# Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a script (JS), and paste the CODE in the console Chrome, but I am a little confused

I'm testing this

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.innerHTML='<iframe onload="frameload()" src="https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/groups/" width="200" height="200"></iframe>';
```

And I'm getting this error

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/groups/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

I'm using JS, From "www.facebook.com", Is it possible to open "https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/groups/" from an iframe?

Thank YOU

EDIT: OR Is there a way to insert this page "https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/groups/" on "https://www.facebook.com" ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the URL `https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/groups/` has set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny', you won't be able to embed this in an iFrame.

Read more on X-Frame-Options here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>   , ,  or . Sites can use this to avoid
>   clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded
>   into other sites.

Comment: Yeah, essentially Facebook isn't allowing the page to be embedded. Nothing OP can do about it.